# What is the complementary slackness conditions for a primal dual pair?

Tags: computer-science, linear-programming

I'm trying to understand what exactly the complementary slackness conditions for a primal dual pair is and how it's calculated.

I understand that we have a given linear programming problem. And that said problem has a dual problem (min becomes max ext.) It seems to me like it has something to do with the difference between the min and max solutions but aren't they supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are talking here about $cx\le by$. Typically for feasible (but non-optimal) solutions for the primal and dual pair we have an inequality here and this becomes an equality when both are optimal.

Comment: So if two you create the dual problem and you find it's solution then the gap is zero? Or if you create the solution then the complementary slackness is equal to the difference between the two?

Comment: You have to be precise with "solution". It can mean feasible solution or optimal solution depending on the context. Optimal means gap=0.

Comment: So iff the the solution is optimal then the gap is 0? How would one go about checking if the solution is zero? (trying to get a grip on linear programming before Christmas). So any detailed explanation that works well for someone with a primarily algorithmic mind would be great as well (I tend to get a bit stuck at the mathematical notations but can understand algorithms really well).

Comment: Checking if the solution is zero? That has no meaning in this context. I think you mean checking if a solution is optimal. There must be a paragraph or even a whole chapter in your book about optimality conditions for an LP.  Yes, optimality implies no gap.

Comment: Sorry I don't really have a book. But yes I do mean if the gap is zero then the solution is optimal, ok good to know but that seems like the inverse of how you would go about this as it seems like your prefer to discovered if the gap is going to be zero ahead of time. Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: I am not following you here. I can recommend Vanderbei's Linear Programming book. It has many more details than can be covered using stackexchange.

Comment: I was wondering how to see if the gap is going to be zero without actually checking if it is (like I have an answer and want to know if I can use it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33247/discussion-between-thijser-and-erwin-kalvelagen).